# IBM Slack links broken

Tags: ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

Does anyone know where I can find working Slack invite links to any of IBM's Slack pages? The Slack links on [this support page](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/support) are all broken. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a link on the [qiskit website](https://qiskit.org/) to the public [Slack](https://qiskit.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtNjQ5OTc5ODM1ODYyLTBlMWY1ZGJiYmZkNjliZTY4MTViNTQ3NzI2ZmU2MzQxZjlhZDZlYTAzZTNlMDU0ZjVmNzEyMzY3OGE1Y2UyNjk). Here you can find channels for talking the various elements of Qiskit and also the IBM Q Experience.