# General mixed integer linear programming problem with quantum computers

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, resource-request, optimization

I was wondering if anyone had a sample code for running a general MILP problem. I saw some coding for some very specific problems and I thought they were kind of far away from what we needed.

$$
\text{minimize } \, D^TX+E^TY \, \text{ s.t. }\\
AX + BY + C \le 0 \\
x_i \ge 0 \\
y_i \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

If anyone has already started generalizations or would like to start I would love to be a part of that. I also tried to get on Slack but was unable to, could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Done. Sorry I though the community might be interested in knowing a bit about one another and the kinds of applications they are working.

Comment: As you're looking for some sample code, I'd consider using the [tag:resource-request] tag. As for the question about Slack, is it a specific channel you're trying to access (such as Qiskit) or is there some other problem? Issues with Slack aren't the sort of thing that's *usually* on topic here but if you join us in [chat], we'll hopefully be able to sort you out on that one!

Comment: [IBM Slack links broken](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6483)

Comment: @ScientiaSystems, would you like to share the info you got in this regard?